# Why createStore calls each reducer 3 times?

Tags: reactjs, redux

i have Redux, i've noticed that createStore call each reducer 3 times, why?

```js
// pageReducer.js
const initialState = {
  year: 2020,
  events: [],
};

const pageReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log(state); //spy for reducer
 
  return { ...state }; 
};
```

```js
// rootReducer.js
export default combineReducers({ page: pageReducer });
```

```js
const store = createStore(rootReducer));

const App = () => {
  const page = useSelector((store) => store.page);
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div>{page.year}</div>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

i see in console, that `createStore()` and `combineReducers()` calling `pageReducer()` 3 times.

Why? For What?
i've thought that for create global state and setting initial state, but 3 times ...

Comment: What do the redux devtools say? What actions are dispatched?

Comment: @HMR, only INITIAL action, but console.log print 3 times